# HDMI to DVI not working on one Monitor, is working on a different brand monitor

Tags: hdmi, dvi

New MB MSI B760-P MB (using Intel UHD 770 GPU) with 1xHDMI and 1xDisplayPort

2 older Illyama E2208HHD monitors (1080p) with only DVI input - both are confirmed working.

Display Port to DVI lead - works on BOTH monitors.

HDMI to DVI lead works on neither monitor - but it DOES work on a different brand (LG W2261VP) monitor, so confirmed that the lead is OK.

As far as I understood HDMI/DVI is only port re-assignment, nothing fancy.

Cable is confirmed working, monitors are confirmed working. What on earth could be the problem?

Comment: 'lead is OK' is actually an incomplete claim. What people generically call DVI has three major versions. Basically, digital single channel, digi 2-channel & analog [a cable can be any or all of these too]. Just because one screen works on any given cable doesn't mean another will unless it uses the same basic configuration. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface & see if you can figure out which it is & also which the working & non-working screens use. See also DVI/HDMI compatibility lower down the page… minefield #2.